# Show on rollover, if content is Visible replace it

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu

I've been struggling to get this thing to work according to my plot.
Basically I wish to accomplish is mend it into a dropdown menu that opens when you hover on a button but changes the content when you rollover other buttons in approximation.

1. Show content on Rollover (slide down animation).
2. Rollover next button - If content is visible replace content
3. on rollout nav region hide content (slide up animation)

**Please see here: [jsfiddle.net/CvhkM/2726](http://jsfiddle.net/CvhkM/2726)
Dropdown menu, if its open, replace content. rollout close again**

Comment: I can hide the content fine, but having problem asking wether its open(shown) or closed. The animation bit I think I can figure out. Also I appreciate the sarcasm. I suck at coding, doesn't mean I'm not trying.

Comment: It's simply a statement of fact. New posters need to be aware of what SO is not. Hence the link.

Comment: look sorry if i offend you, but this is not helping. ive been at this the whole morning its freaking 8pm now, still no luck. what is it that you want from me?

Comment: Nothing. http://www.google.com/insidesearch/tipstricks/ :)

Comment: C'mon. I can show you a really small example, but you really have to post some code: HTML, CSS(not needed always), and a JS/jQ where you are stuck (You said it's all morning... so you surely have something to show us.)

Comment: BTW. look at the right side of this screen and find the tab called *'Related'* (...to your question.). Enjoy.

Comment: I cant do it, too complicated. massive headache. I'll work out a different design. thanks for your interest anyway.

Comment: Still havent giving up. Please help with the code above, how do I add a delay? and a second button next to Content, if its open, replace content

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, I accidentally edited your fiddle, but is this what you meant?  I'm not 100% clear on what you wanted done, but I assume it's something like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/CvhkM/2724/

I think your problem was that you were using that hoverIntent() function, instead of the default hover(), which works fine.  Again, not sure if this is what you were looking for.

**EDIT** (again)

Was this more what you were going for?

http://jsfiddle.net/sSynX/1/

Comment: Hi Luke, thanks but this is more an accordion, the reason I use HoverIntent is that it adds a delay, without making the divs dance. This is what I want: http://jsfiddle.net/CvhkM/2726/  but now when i try to go over the sub menu it folds in.

Comment: Err...nope, this is my intent: 1. rollover button1 - slide out subs. 2. rollover button2 - if sub window is out, replace the content with subs of button2. if not show.. Essentially its one sliding div, just hiding and revealing the sub content when its open. since those two buttons are in approximation it doesnt need to close again. i'll play a bit more see where it takes me

Comment: I think I understand what you mean now, take another look at it, I just updated the fiddle.

Comment: One more thing; do you mind explaining a little bit of what is happening?

Comment: I am having a bit of problem porting this to my HTML. although I wrapped it in $(document).ready(function(){     }); and jQuery(document).ready(function(){  }); with both script attached no reaction. What am I missing?

Comment: Sorry, just figured it out, jsFiddle.com/draft  solved it for me after creating an account. Thanks again!

Comment: Sorry for not replying, I've been real busy!  Glad you got it figured though.

Comment: Luke, sorry actually I have little favour to ask you. I've been trying to remove the 3rd button from the dropdown loop (no luck, except creating an entire new btn) - also is it possible to stop the slide out animation midways (on rollout)? :/ You've been really helpful, much appreciated!

Comment: Yea cool! Oops i didnt meant to remove the 3rd button li's :) it just doesnt have a sub. Another thing, is it possible to get rid of that 2 pixel line when you do a super quick rollover? :) clearly i'm a designer. If you got something I can assist you on let me know - I wish to return the favour!

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, this solves it! Let me know whenever you need a favour.

Comment: Hey Luke, how are you doing? Really sorry to bother again but 1. how can I give the button(dropdown) link an active colour/element when the mouse enters? 2. if I place div(buttons) inside the 'content' div it close once the mouse enters. :( http://jsfiddle.net/amateurstuff/sSynX/8/

Comment: Hey, you wanna use a `:hover` css selector for the rollover, and that second problem sounds like a bubbling issue.  You might need to make a few calls to `event.stopPropagation()`, where `event` is the event object passed into your event callback.  Hope that makes sense, if not, google is your friend :)